# Sum of kth roots ($\sum\sqrt[k]{m}$)

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, summation, divergent-series

I'm trying to find an asymptotic to $$S(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt[k]{m}$$ From computational tests, it seems to grow nearly as slowly as $n$. However even $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sqrt[k]{m}-1$$ diverges (for $m\neq1$) by the comparison test.

I'm thinking it might be something like $n\log{\log n}$, but I don't know how to show it.

**Update:** So it turns out to be closer to $n\sqrt[n]{m}$. Does anybody know if there is a nice formula?

Comment: Hint: substitute $S(n)$ with integral $$\int\limits_0^n m^{-x}dx$$

Comment: Ah, of course. Though you mean $m^{x^{-1}}$, right?

Comment: yes you are right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have :
$$ M^{1/k} = 1 + \frac{1}{k} \ln M + \frac{1}{2} \ln^2 M \frac{1}{k^2} + O(1/k^3)$$
Since
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} = \ln n + \gamma + \frac{1}{2n} + O(1/n^2)$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6} - \frac{1}{n} + O(1/n^2)$$
we deduce :
$$\sum_{k=1}^n M^{1/k} = n + \ln M. \ln n + C + (\ln M + \ln^2 M) \frac{1}{2n} + O(1/n^2),$$
for some constant $C$.

Comment: One small correction: $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}\color{#C00000}{-}\frac1n+O(1/n^2)$$

Comment: Constante? Habla español?

Comment: This is very nice in terms of $n$, but of course, it doesn't capture growth in terms of $M$, since the $O(1/n^2)$ term contains arbitrarily large $\Omega(\ln^k M)$ terms; and we know the sum grows at least as fast as $M$.

Answer (score 1):

For small enough $x>0$ we have $e^x-1\in(x,2x)$. Furthermore, $\sqrt[k]{m}-1=m^{1/k}-1=e^{(\ln m)/k}-1$. As $k$ increases $x$ will approach $0$ and hence for large enough $k$ we have 
$$ \frac{\ln m}{k}<\sqrt[k]{m}-1<\frac{2\ln m}{k}\,.$$ 
Since 
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k \sim \ln n \longrightarrow \infty $$
for $n\to\infty$, by the sandwich lemma, your sum will also go to infinity for $n\to\infty$ with logarithmic speed.

Answer (score 1):

After Ralph's answer I'd like to detail this a bit.  *[update](upps, after I've posted this it seems user10670 was 30 sec's ahead)*

After some standard-manipulation with the Carleman-matrices for $$ m \to  \sqrt[x]{1+m}-1 =\exp( \log(1+m) / x)-1 $$
I come to the following asymptotic.
We need also the expression for the sum of the first consecutive reciprocals 
$$ s_p(a,n) = \sum_{k=a}^n \frac 1{k^p} $$
then we get
$$S_m(n) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty {\log(m)^k s_k(2,n) \over k!}  $$
and clearly this contains a $\zeta(1)-1$-expression in $s_1(2,n)$ if *n* is assumed to go to infinity.

---

*unchecked remark:* To get this possibly converging I think you should not only reduce by 1 but also by the next term, so  something like $$S_m(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt[k]{m}-1+m/k $$ to eliminate the $\zeta(1)$-expression

Comment: Given $\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt[k]{m}-1$ diverges against positive infinity, I don't think this will work..

Answer (score 1):

We can get some intuition for this by taking the integral
$$\int_1^n m^{1/x} = n + \frac{m}{\log m} + (\log m) (\log n-\log\log m-\gamma+1) + O\left(\frac{m}{\log^2 m} + \frac{\log^2 m}{n}+\frac{1}{m^2}\right)$$.

However, we know that the actual result has to grow at least as fast as $m$.

The best, reasonably simple, formula I've found so far is: $$m + n + \log n \log m - 1$$.

If $m$ and $n$ grows at the same speed, it doesn't quite grow fast enough (loses about 0.2% at $m=n=10^5$), but if one of $m$ or $n$ grows fastest, it is nearly perfect.

[image]

Plotted with $m=2$, $0<n\leq10$